# Expected an indented block after Importing?

Tags: python-2.7, import, indentation, panda3d

Today I was coding and i ran into this unusual error.
Here is my code:

```
from direct.showbase.ShowBase import ShowBase
import cogManager

class application(ShowBase):

    def __init__(self):
        ShowBase.__init__(self)

playApplication = application()
playApplication.run()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CogCreator.py", line 2, in <module>
  import cogManager
File "C:\Users\GeekyGamerGavin\Documents\Toontown Phase Files\NEW\cogManager.p
y", line 4

                    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

But the code works when I remove

```
import cogManager
```

Could I have some help? I'm confused!

EDIT: I dont have spaces / tabs mixed!

EDIT: Fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a tab on an empty line, or are mixing tabs and spaces. Following [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) coding standards, indentation should be 4 spaces per level.

Answer (score 0):

Try indenting def **init**(self):

```
from direct.showbase.ShowBase import ShowBase
import cogManager

class application(ShowBase):

    def __init__(self):
        ShowBase.__init__(self)

playApplication = application()
playApplication.run()
```